# Remember last logged in users in Azure Active Directory Xamarin Forms

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, adal, xamarin.uwp

I am using Azure AD to authenticate the user in my Xamarin forms app and what I want to achieve in my UWP app that if one user lets says signed in the app and then signed out. On Next login flow Azure AD should show list of user who were logged in on that particular device so user can pick the user and just enter password.

In my case if I signout the user then it always start the flow from asking the email and password

Here is code snippet for signout

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"{tenantUrl}/{tenantId}");
                authContext.TokenCache.Clear();

                Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter myFilter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
                var cookieManager = myFilter.CookieManager;
                var cookieUri = new System.Uri(tenantUrl);
                HttpCookieCollection myCookieJar = cookieManager.GetCookies(cookieUri);
                foreach (HttpCookie cookie in myCookieJar)
                {
                    cookieManager.DeleteCookie(cookie);
                }
```

P.S: Seems to be issue for UWP ADAL package since samething is working fine on iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question!

There was a fix needed in ADAL (a new release needs to happen, so anything higher then 5.0.2-preview will have the fix) to handle this in UWP.

Add this code to your app:

```cs
var x = Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
```

Take the value (something like this: `ms-app://s-1-15-2-111638678-219698677-36916742-1909548894-372823757-39941306-27685825/`) and register the value as a redirectUri in the portal for this app.

Then, back in the code, 
instead of passing in the above value (x) as the redirectURI, pass in **null**. ADAL/MSAL will set the redirect uri to `https://sso` which will route through the WebAuthenticationManager, and you should now see a list of the accounts, like on iOS.

You also might be interested in this [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-interactively---Public-client-application-flows#getting-the-redirect-uri-in-the-case-of-windows-universal-apps) as well, especially if having issues on corp net.

Answer (score 0):

With ADAL package, you won't see last logged in users email id. But if you use **MSAL** package by default, you will be able to see the list of last logged in users email id. I tried on my local machine and with MSAL package I am able to see the user's email id list. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

I hope the above information is helpful.